# Upload images and metadata to public Amazon S3 bucket with Python requests

Tags: python, upload, amazon-s3, python-requests

I know, there's the boto library for Python, however, all I'd like to do is uploading a lot of image files including metadata to a public S3 bucket. The images should go into various sub-directories inside the bucket.

With cURL, this is supposed to be working:

```
curl -v -F "key=test/test.jpg" -F "file=@test.jpg" http://my-public-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

So I figure that should be doable with urllib, urllib2 and/or Python requests only. But how? I'm totally new to Amazon S3 ... and cURL.

Also what's the best way for storing some meta data along with the images? An additional JSON-string file?

Comment: What's the reason why you want to go around `boto`?  Just because you don't know it maybe?  It will be a much shorter and more readable solution if done using that library.  Unless you have a good reason to not use it of course ...

Comment: boto is a rather huge package and AFAIK no request signature is required for uploading to public buckets. So why using a whole library instead of a simple requests call ...?

Comment: To get all the additional stuff for free you'd have to do otherwise manually like error checking etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cURL string translates into roughly the following:

```
import requests

url = 'http://my-public-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/'
files = {
    'key': ('', 'test/test.jpg'),
    'file': open('test.jpg', 'rb'),
}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

The general form of Requests' multipart upload syntax is found in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974452/1401686).

Comment: how to add metadata to the image? I am using presigned post url and I have tried adding metadata fields starting with x-amz-meta in headers but though the upload is successful the metadata is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

Using `boto` (version 2.6.0) you'd do it like this:

```
import boto

connection = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = connection.get_bucket('mybucket')
key = bucket.new_key('myimage.jpg')
key.set_contents_from_filename('myimage.jpg')
key.set_metadata(...)
```

Make sure you've got the credentials in the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks ... The thing is: we don't have the credentials. It's not our bucket, but we need to fill it with content needed by our partner - that's why the bucket is public/open.

Comment: If the bucket access is not limited, then I guess also without credentials you won't get an error.

Comment: Thx, I'll give it a try tomorrow - late here in Germany now ;-) Out of interest: still would like to know how sending a file is done via Python Requests :)

Comment: Greetings from Berlin ;-)

Comment: Nope - won't work without credentials. I got it working with pure Requests, though.

Answer (score 1):

Works with Python Requests only:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('my_public_bucket', files={'file': open('/path/test.txt', 'rb')}, data={'key': 'test/test.txt'})
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload to a signed url and requests I had to do this:

```
with open('photo_1.jpg', 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
result = requests.put(url=upload_url, headers={}, data=content)
```

This is bad because it loads everything into memory, but it should get you past the initial hump.

Also when using curl I had to use the a different option:

```
curl -X PUT --upload-file photo_1.jpg <url>
```

Note: When I created the url at my server with boto I set headers=None so that headers would not be an issue.