# Mulitpart POST requests in Python without filename

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am looking to send the below type of POST request from a python API:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarykQ0pCUTfUvTIocvw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

SSF_nY4PQT8190207X10Showtest.gz
------WebKitFormBoundarykQ0pCUTfUvTIocvw--
```

Please note that the `SSF_nY4PQT8190207X10test.gz` is not a file I am sending. I am asking the server to do some action on this file.

Following below links I tried to do this by `t = s.post(url, headers=headers, files = {'filename': ('', 'content')}, verify=False)`

[Multipart POST using python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965453/multipart-post-using-python-requests/19974452#19974452)

https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/935

But getting this header

```
--63fb60c0045e41439442713330f821ce
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename=""

content
--63fb60c0045e41439442713330f821ce--
```

How do I get rid of `filename=""` in my request.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried passing `None` as filename? Not sure this will work though

Comment: This did the trick :) thanks so much.. Was stuck on this for more than an hour

Comment: Can you send that as an answer so that I am mark this resolved

Answer (score 0):

Tried to play a round with this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from requests import Request, Session

s = Session()
files={'filename': 'content'}
url="http://localhost"
req = Request('POST',  url, files=files)

prepped = s.prepare_request(req)
print(prepped.body)
```

But whatever i did, the `Content_Disposition` always had the `Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename=""` parameters.

So i looked at the Requests source: https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L165 which referred me to Urllib3 https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/fields.py#L174 <s>and it seems those parameters will always be there even if you provide empty strings. Don't see a way to override them.</s>

**Edit**
From one of the comments above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from requests import Request, Session

s = Session()
files={'filename': (None,'content')}
url="http://localhost"
req = Request('POST',  url, files=files)

prepped = s.prepare_request(req)
print(prepped.body)
```

Comment: Mikhail Burshteyn's suggestion about using None in place of empty string worked fine for me. Consider this thread answered and done :) thanks for your help